# Regex crossword

Tags: computer-puzzle, crosswords

I can't believe this old-but-gold piece hasn't been shared here. It's a regex crossword puzzle!

[image: Crossword]

Here's a [nicely printable PDF](http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/2013/coinheist.com/rubik/a_regular_crossword/grid.pdf).

Kudos for this one goes to a [competition held by MIT in 2013](http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/2013/). The answer to this particular puzzle is also [listed there](http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/2013/coinheist.com/rubik/a_regular_crossword/answer/index.html), so this isn't much of a competition - I'm just sharing something nice to play with that I myself enjoyed immensely. :)

Comment: Does each regex have to consume the entire row/column? Or does the regex just have to match at least once?

Comment: @plasticinsect - Entire row

Comment: For fan of regex crosswords there is a website full of them: https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, but that's kinda like easy mode compared to this thing. :)

Comment: @Vilx-: Given I've not got through all the ones on that website I feel this might not be a bad thing! ;-)

Comment: @Chris - It's fair enough. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This beautiful hive took me 2 hours :P
I realllllllllllly like this regex crossword(more like sudoku instead, need to derive one by one)!

> [image]

My paperwork here :P

> [image]

Useful for Regex checking:

> [Regex101](http://regex101.com)

Remark:

> I've found this site: [Regex Cross­word](https://regexcrossword.com/)
>   For whom loves Regex crosswords :P

Comment: Aaaand you get the checkmark! Great work! :)

Comment: There is twice OM and no MS on the second horizontal row, is this normal? @Vilx-

Comment: @ArnaudMortier - Is that the one that says `(DI|NS|TH|OM)*`? Then yes, it's correct. It matches the regex.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier this is for checking regex pattern: https://regex101.com/ :)

Answer (score 4):

I loved this puzzle. I'm super impressed with @Conifers who completed it in 2 hours. Took me something closer to 5 hours, though I did it in burst of 30 minutes. Here's mine:
[image]

Comment: We are Regex fanatics :P

Comment: I'm kinda doing it right now at work, 5 minutes at a time. :D